# Set a css attribute to important through javascript

Tags: javascript, css

On my page I want to set the attribute display to `block!important` when there's a specific string in the url,

I've been doing some research, but can't find the correct answer. Using the code below I can set the `background-color: green!important` on the body, but I don't know how to target something else (the `"loginActive"` id element).

```
:javascript
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("sign_up") > -1) {
    document.body.style.setProperty ("background-color", "green", "important");
    document.getElementById("loginActive").style.display = "block", "important";
  }
```

Any tips on how I can set `display: block!important` on the element `#loginActive` ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `!important` if you're setting styles on the element itself, unless there's something else that's `!important` elsewhere.  If the one elsewhere is `!important`, presumably whoever added it decided it shouldn't be overridden.  Generally, the use of `!important` is seen as a bad solution to a CSS issue that will come back to bite you, as it sounds it may have done here.

Comment: Can you use Jquery ?

Comment: I'm no fan of using !important, but I'm using it with a angular ng-show function.

Comment: `document.getElementById("loginActive").style.display = "block", "important";` – that makes no sense, resp. it doesn’t do what you think it does. (Go look up the JS _comma operator_, if you want to know what your line actually means.) And I don’t understand the question – in the line above, you are able to set a style property with important for the body – so what is stopping you from using that exact same syntax in the second line as well …?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var item = document.getElementById("loginActive");
item.style. display = 'block !important';
```

Or

```
item.setAttribute('style', 'display:block !important');
```

But you shouldn't do that

Comment: That's no different then `document.getElementById("loginActive").style.display = "block", "important";`

Comment: `:javascript  if(window.location.href.indexOf("sign_up") > -1) { var item = document.getElementById("loginActive");  item.style.setProperty ("display", "block", "important");  }` changed the code a bit, workse now.

Comment: My bad, setAttribute actually works better, but you should consider using a class with display: !important and append with to the element

Comment: @alucardu: Of course that is significantly different – mainly because in your code, you are not setting `important` _at all_ (you just have a string literal “on its own”, using the comma _operator_ after the first assignment.)